# Google Sheets Script Error - Cannot convert Array to Object[][]

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I'm working on a script to encode data in fields for insertion into HTML (the cells contain words like `Planétarium` and `Rua João Bettega, 01`). I am getting an error and don't know what to do with it. The error says **"Cannot convert Array to Object[][]"**

I'm definitely passing a two-dim array to `.setValues()`, so I know that's not it (found that to be a common problem). Any ideas? Here's my function:

```
// columns[] and columns2encode[] are set in the scope above this function
function _encodeData() {
  var sheet = _getSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var rowCnt = data.length;
  var colCnt = data[0].length;
  var data2set = new Array(rowCnt-1); // creates array w/ row.length indeces
  var colEncodeIndexList = [];
  var origVal, encodedVal, range, cell; // used later in for loop(s)

  toast('Start Encoding Data');

  // loop every row
  for(var ri = 0; ri < data.length; ri++) {
    if(ri !== 0) {
      data2set[ri] = new Array(colCnt); // creates array w/ length of ~ 29
    }

    // loop every cell (column entry in the given row)
    for(var ci = 0; ci < data[ri].length; ci++) {
      // get text content of current cell
      origVal = data[ri][ci];

      // if first row, headers - save matches in array for later
      if(ri === 0) { // I split the ifs so inArray isn't called EVERY time
        if(inArray(columns2encode, origVal)) { // add col header if "on the list"
          colEncodeIndexList.push(ci);
        }
      } else { // isn't the header row
        // if ! first row, values - col num must be in saved headers to encode OR it's a number
        if(!inArray(colEncodeIndexList, ci) || typeof origVal === 'number') {
          // just use origVal
          data2set[ri][ci] = origVal;
        } else {
          // use encodedVal
          encodedVal = _htmlEncode(origVal);

          data2set[ri][ci] = encodedVal;
        }
      } // else
    } // for (cells/cols)
  } // for (rows)

  // Now pass array of arrays (data) to setValues()
  var setRange = sheet.getRange(2, 1, (data.length-1), data[0].length);//.getA1Notation(); // starts at 2, 1 (row 2, col 1) to ignore column header
  setRange.setValues(data2set);

  toast('Finished Encoding Data');
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Run the code from the script editor. It should tell you which line throws the error. Please tell us which line

Comment: Error is on line 130 (the `setRange.setValues(data2set);` method call).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `data2set[0]` is never initialized (it is always NULL).

The easiest way to fix the problem is to remove the data2set[0] before outputting to the spreadsheet:

```
  data2set.shift(); // remove 1st item
  setRange.setValues(data2set);
```

Comment: Good find! I thought I had accounted for the 0 index, but it seems not. Thanks for the help, @daniel